# ActiveRestClient child classes inherit base class settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-rest-client

While trying to create a base class using `ActiveRestClient` in Rails 4.2.0, I've run into an issue trying to configure settings in a base class and have those inherited by child classes.

```
class Foo::Base < ActiveRestClient::Base
  base_url "https://example.com/api/v1"
  username "testuser"
  password "testpassword"
  request_body_type :json
end

class Foo::Thing < Foo::Base
  get :all, "/things"
end
```

I get no errors but when performing `Foo::Thing.all` it throws `URI::InvalidURIError`. The same method works if the settings from `Foo::Base` are moved into `Foo::Thing`.

It also works if the base class modifies the settings directly in the parent class using `ActiveRestClient::Base.base_url = "..."` but that is a global change and not ideal.

I have several models that all use the same base settings, so it would make sense to set them in a base class and inherit from it.

Comment: ActiveRestClient isn't developed anymore, check out [https://github.com/flexirest/flexirest](flexirest)